# binomial glm where number of trials is also a predictor

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, binomial-distribution

I am modeling the probability of success $p_i$ under a binomial framework. In fact I am actually modeling $x_i \sim Bin\left( n_i, p_i\right)$ being the number of trial varying along each observation. Nevertheless for the particular research I am carrying out I have grounded reasons to assume $p_i = f\left(n_i\right)$. Can I use $n_i$ as a predictor of $p_i$? Is the Binomial model still appropriate?

Comment: Can you give us some more context? Do you have any idea about the form of the function $f$? Sample size? I guess context could be important here.